# Is there any other setting inside IntelliJ for Java VM system properties?

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber

Because of constraints with our internal Maven repositories/proxies I need to use the following VM entry as a system property in order for my Cucumber/Selenium tests to work:

`-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=src/test/resources/drivers/windows/chromedriver.exe`

However, the only place I could figure out where to place and have it picked up is in the Run Configurations, as follows:

[image]

However, due to the way I believe Cucumber/IntelliJ works, every time I debug a specific Cucumber test,

[image]

It always creates a brand new Run Configuration and I have to manually add this entry.

Is there another setting inside IntelliJ to set this property or a way for it to be part of the 'default' for when new configurations are automatically created?

Comment: There is a thing called template configuration that you can specify so intellij will use it instead of creating a temporary one. Read more about it here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html

Comment: Thanks, well that wasn't obvious ;) I noticed unless I'm wrong, but in order to get access to the created configuration for each test you have to first run it before you can then edit it as it is only created after a first run. Anyway, this seems to work, so just add it as an answer if you want the points.

Comment: as long as it helped, I'm ok :)